# C# Recursion Duplicate Id

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have a recursion method that will set the Node Id using an kind of index , I have been scratching my head hard since it keeps complaining that I have duplicate Ids.

I am sure integer type is passed by value, so, I am not sure what is wrong here.

```
IList<DocumentNode> contents = new List<DocumentNode>();
int index = 0;
LoadContents(null, index++, result, contents);  

private void LoadContents(DocumentNodeparentNode, int nodeId, WordContent wordContent, IList<DocumentNode> contents)
{    
    foreach (OtheClassContent childContent in wordContent.ChildrenContent)
    {
        var node = new DocumentNodeViewModel(nodeId,
            parentNode?.NodeId,
            childContent.SortOrder,
            childContent.Depth);

        contents.Add(node);
        nodeId++;
        LoadContents(node, nodeId, childContent, contents);
    }
}

// This line wont work
IDictionary<int, int?> myDictionary = contents.ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a.ParentId);
```

Document Node is simple tree node structure

```
public class DocumentNode
{
    public DocumentNode(
        int nodeId,
        int? parentNodeId, 
        short sortOrder,
        short branchLevel)
    {
        NodeId = nodeId;

        SortOrder = sortOrder;
        BranchLevel = branchLevel;
        ParentNode = null;
        ParentNodeId = parentNodeId;
        ChildNodes = Enumerable.Empty<DocumentNode>();
    }

    public int NodeId { get; private set; }
    public int? ParentNodeId { get; private set; }
    public short SortOrder { get; private set; }
    public DocumentNode ParentNode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DocumentNode> ChildNodes { get; set; }
    public short BranchLevel { get; private set; }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Example: you create node with `nodeID` = 3 and increment to 4. Then recursive call creates nodes 4,5,6. But back in original `nodeID` is still 4. Loop continues and you create node 4 - but it's already created. Problem solved if you pass `nodeID` by `ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the `nodeId` by value, so here's what happens:

```
Child1: nodeId = 0
    Grandchild1_1: nodeId = 1
    Grandchild1_2: nodeId = 2
Child2: nodeId = 1
    Grandchild2_1: nodeId = 2
    Grandchild2_2: nodeId = 3
...
```

If you pass it by reference, all the recursion calls can increase the same value, producing this:

```
Child1: nodeId = 0
    Grandchild1_1: nodeId = 1
    Grandchild1_2: nodeId = 2
Child2: nodeId = 3
    Grandchild2_1: nodeId = 4
    Grandchild2_2: nodeId = 5
...
```

---

Basically, by passing as value, you are creating a new copy of the `nodeId` for each child. Once you return from the lower-level recursive call, the higher-level one can't see any changes to the `nodeId` because all changes were made to the copy.

Alternative to using `ref` is returning the last node count from the function. So here is the simplified idea of your two alternatives.

References:

```
private void RecursiveCallWithRefs (Node current, ref int nodeId)
{
    foreach (var child in current.Children)
    {
        child.FillOutContents(nodeId);
        ++nodeId;
        RecursiveCallWithRefs(child, ref nodeId);
    }
}
```

Return values:

```
private int RecursiveCallWithReturns (Node current, int nodeId)
{
    foreach (var child in current.Children)
    {
        child.FillOutContents(nodeId);
        nodeId = RecursiveCallWithReturns(child, nodeId + 1);
    }

    return nodeId;
}
```

---

Of course, if I were you, I'd wrap this in a more abstract call:

```
private void FillOutNodesWithRefs (Node startingNode)
{
    int startingId = 0;
    RecursiveCallWithRefs(startingNode, ref startingId);
}

private void FillOutNodesWithReturns (Node startingNode)
{
    RecursiveCallWithReturns(startingNode, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that integer is passed by value. It seems while adding a node in your foreach loop, you add a node, then send the incremented id for recursion and the same id is being used by the main call as well as for recursive call.

Say for e.g., you have 2 elements in wordContent.ChildrenContent the first time you call it, it creates the first node with id = 0 and increments it to 1 and then calls the recursion with id = 1. Suppose you have 2 elements in the wordContent.ChildrenContent in the recursion call too, in that case, the recursion adds new nodes with ids 1 and 2 and the control goes back to the main method. Here, the id is still 1 and now another node is created with id 1.

I think you'll be alright if you pass the id with reference.

```
IList<DocumentNode> contents = new List<DocumentNode>();
int index = 0;
LoadContents(null, ref index++, result, contents);  

private void LoadContents(DocumentNode parentNode, ref int nodeId, WordContent wordContent, IList<DocumentNode> contents)
{    
    foreach (OtheClassContent childContent in wordContent.ChildrenContent)
    {
        var node = new DocumentNodeViewModel(nodeId,
            parentNode?.NodeId,
            childContent.SortOrder,
            childContent.Depth);

        contents.Add(node);
        nodeId++;
        LoadContents(node, ref nodeId, childContent, contents);
    }
}

// This line wont work
IDictionary<int, int?> myDictionary = contents.ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a.ParentId);
```